# Global variable vs. local-static variable for storing state

Tags: programming-practices, c, storage

I am writing an application for my graduation coursework, in C, using GTK+ UI library. Sometimes I ask for user input, which I need to save for later use.

The doubt comes on how to store this data. I didn't want to create global variables because I was told countless times not to use them. However, I need to interchange data between functions which don't call each other directly (because of slot-signal pattern, I don't have a function that's always accessible after the event loop starts), thus needing some independent storage.

For this purpose I designed a getter-like function which reads similar to this:

```
char *store_data(char *data, int clear) {
    static char *stored_data = NULL;

    if(data == NULL) {
        if(clear) {
            stored_data = NULL;
        } else {
            return stored_data;
        }
    } else {
        stored_data = data;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Is such a construct OK or should I simply use a global variable instead?

Comment: I'd advise against this - I'd use a struct which holds all common state and explicitly pass a pointer to it into every function that uses it. If you don't like that, go back to a global variable.

Comment: @lethal-guitar the problem is I don't have a function that is always accessed, since GTK+ is event-driven. Where would I put this struct?

Comment: I see.. well if all your event handlers are in one module, you can use a `static` global variable - it's only accessible inside that module, which I consider much better than a truly global variable. It's a bit similar to a class' private data in OO-languages.

Comment: You can then add a non-static "getter" function which returns the variable's value.

Comment: @lethal-guitar thanks, I think this is indeed a better approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I already said in the comments, I'd propose using a `static` global variable:

```
// Some *.c file:
static char *stored_data = NULL;
```

This will only be accessible from functions in the same module (`.c`-file), which is preferable to a truly global variable. If you like, you can still provide "getter" and "setter" functions in the same module, which are non-`static` and declared in the corresponding header file.

It's still global state, but it's now encapsulated in the relevant module. It's also clearer and cleaner than the "static local" approach, in my eyes.

Comment: Can you comment why you think this is "clearer and cleaner" than the static local approach. A static local variable will only be accessible in that function, whereas a static global variable can be accidentally used by other functions in that file.

Comment: @mercury0114 sure can. The OP explicitly said "I need to interchange data between functions". "clearer and cleaner" is in reference to the proposed solution in the OP's post, which to me is overly complicated for what is needed here.

The cleanest solution would be to pass a pointer to some kind of context object to all the functions that need that data, which I also suggested. But the OP was working within a fixed framework which doesn't support that, so a `static` global is the next best solution in that case (imo).